500 ошибка, отдать html страницу
htaccess
ErrorDocument 500 /500.html

Прописал правило на 500 ошибку, в php коде намеренно сделал ошибку. Но вместо того, чтобы отдать документ 500.html, браузер пишет мол не удалось отобразить ошибку.
Код ответа страницы: 500
Возможно ли когда в синтаксисе php допущена ошибка, отобразить документ?

А почему именно синтаксиса? Она так часто встречается?

Нет, практически не встречается. Использую try {} catch (Error $e) { отдаем страницу } пару раз срабатывала из-за чего так и не понял.  Попытался инсценировать 500 ошибку, чтобы проверить правило, что та не вышло...

так надо посмотреть в логи....это раз.....и включить отображение ошибок - это два....и всё увидишь

А зачем правило, если в catch можно точно так же сделать readfile($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/500.html");?

попробуйте добавить домен ErrorDocument 500 https://example.com/500.html

ошибка 500 это упал сервер. как он может что-то обработать? Могу наврать, но обрабатывают ошибки 4ХХ или 3ХХ
